# update and select query together to update table data from same table

Tags: mysql

I having a table given in image wich having columns a b c d thats stored in column ans i want to update the table's conclusion column with ans columns value. i make a select query to get the value of a b c or d which is stored in ans column .but now i am confuse how to update that value in conclusion with update and select together.

```
select CASE WHEN (SELECT ans FROM `test` q1 WHERE `ans`!='' AND q1.id=q2.id)='A' THEN A ELSE CASE WHEN (SELECT ans FROM `test` q1 WHERE `ans`!='' AND q1.id=q2.id)='B' THEN B ELSE CASE WHEN (SELECT ans FROM `test` q1 WHERE `ans`!='' AND q1.id=q2.id)='C' THEN C ELSE D END END END as data from test q2
```

### [image]

Comment: You should not store same Information twice

Comment: yes i know but some times the conclusion ans ans column will be different but right now i need to update with same data.

Comment: you mean select from test2 and insert to test1?

Comment: i want the value of the column which is stored in ans column like first ans column having B as value so i want the value of B column in conclusion bbbbb2541. as so on.how to update it whith given select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need this

```
Update Test 
set conclusion = CASE ans    
                    WHEN 'A' THEN A  
                    WHEN 'B' THEN B  
                    WHEN 'C' THEN C 
                     ELSE D 
                  END
```

Comment: Thanks buddy its worked.ohh its so simple and i was using it in wrong way.

Comment: Yes .. sometimes a second point of view show the most easy way .. anyway if my asnwer is right please mark it as accepted .. thanks